# ggplot2 gives me the blues in R in scatter plots, how do I do a spectral color set?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I run this ggplot2 code, the legend is all shades of blue.  This is rather hard to tell light blue from dark blue.  I would like to have it be a spectral image (heat map).  I have googled and tried many things and it stays blue.

```
require(ggplot2)
d=data.frame(x=runif(100),y=runif(100),z=runif(100))
g = ggplot(data=d) + 
    geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=z),size=1)
g = g + theme_bw()     
print(g)
```

I apologize if I am not seeing the obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add `scale_colour_gradient()` like this:

```
g <- ggplot(data=d) + 
     geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=z),size=1) +
     scale_colour_gradient(low="blue", high="red")
g <- g + theme_bw()
```

This changes the scale from blue to red instead of light blue to dark blue. There are probably nicer ways by using RColorBrewer; I'll see if I can find something better.

**Update**

As described in the comments, @VincentBonhomme quickly found what I was looking for:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
g <- ggplot(data=d) + 
     geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=z),size=1) +
     scale_colour_gradientn(colours = brewer.pal(10, "Spectral"))
g <- g + theme_bw()
```

---

To view the different palettes provided by RColorBrewer one can use

```
library(RColorBrewer)
display.brewer.all()
```

Comment: as a complement, with RColorBrewer, you can try: 
`g + scale_colour_gradientn(colours = brewer.pal(10, "Spectral"))`

Comment: @VincentBonhomme Nice - that was exactly what I was trying to find.

Comment: @VincentBonhomme I have included your comment in my answer; hope this is OK for you. If you prefer you can post the answer yourself - I will then remove the update of the post.

Comment: my pleasure, don't worry ;-)